# Will closing a MacBook cancel restoration from Time Machine backup?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, restore

I'm currently restoring a MacBook from a Time Machine backup. Estimated time for completion is 3 hours. I'm traveling and will have to pack it up in 30 minutes. Will that cancel the restoration process? If so, how delicate would such a cancellation be? Might it lead to a corrupted state?

Comment: What MacBook are you using (year and pro/air/regular)?

Comment: @ScottGroppenbecker MacBook Pro 15" 2016, but should be the same for all models, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will put the MacBook to sleep, which effectively pauses the restore.

Since you're restoring from external media even if the MacBook itself doesn't recover nicely when woken back up you could simply start another restore from the same Time Machine drive.

Comment: Ended up simply closing the MacBook and hoping for the best. Turned out not to be an issue. Restore resumed right where it left off after waking from sleep (although seemingly at only a third of the former speed, 11 instead of 36 MB/s).